# How to make a heat map based on Grid layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, heat-map

The way this image is displayed is very clear, it shows the correlation of two (or more) attributes in space. This picture should be drawn in Arcgis, it should be a combination of grid layer, polygon layer and a point layer. My layers and the data structure are supposed to be similar to it, I'm trying to draw it in QGIS but without success, can someone give me some guidance?

The layers I already have are:

1. a polygon layer (Figure 1) with multiple attributes;
2. a point layer (Figure 2) centroided from Figure 1.
3. a grid layer (Fig. 3), where the attributes of each grid are the average of the points of Fig. 2 contained therein.

In particular, I don't know how this heatmap is generated, it seems to be based on the grid layer (is it?), but I didn't find a way to generate a heatmap based on the grid layer in QGIS

[image]

Comment: Heatmaps normaly are based on point features - not on rasters. Same in your picture where heatmap based on the centroids of the polygon feature, may be weighted with a certain value: the classes on the right side in the legend. There is a good tutorial from Ujaval Gandhi: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/creating_heatmaps.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply！ I guess this heat map is based on grid layer because the author said in the previous figure that grid layer is helpful to analyze the spatial distribution of points and attributes in a figure with uneven distribution of points. In this diagram itself, the heat map is distributed in a square grid, and the units of each heat map are shown as squares themselves. I haven't found a way to make a point-based heatmap look like this, or is this just a symbolic form?

Comment: Heatmap are raster (usually generated from point as pointed by @eurojam) so they always show as a grid (but depending on the map scale and raster cell size the grided structure could be more or less visible)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see, so it's possible that the grid layer is being centroids to get a new point layer for the heatmap.